# Подскажите развивающуюся CMS на yii2

Tags: yii2

Здравствуйте.
Подскажите какую-нибудь развивающуюся CMS на основе yii framework 2 для новичков.
На гитхабе нашла только полу-заброшенные и ещё вот это https://github.com/yiifans/lulucms, но там даже документации нет, а мне сложно разобраться.
Спасибо!

Comment: я бы порекомендовал http://easyiicms.com потому что CMS это все-таки не только E-commerce.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[DotPlant2](https://github.com/devgroup-ru/dotplant2) - CMS для интернет-магазинов.

[Документация](http://docs.dotplant.ru/ru/Getting_Started.html) на русском языке есть.

Сейчас проект в альфе и активно развивается. 1 июня запланирован релиз беты. В gitter чате всегда помогут с проблемами!

Comment: Спасибо, но мне бы для обычного сайта компании - интернет-магазин не нужен

Comment: Ну реализовывать на своем сайте функционал магазина вовсе необязательно. Можно обойтись модулями управления контентом, формами.

Answer (score 5):

http://easyiicms.com/ - документация кое-какая есть на английском.
На демо-версии есть также примеры вызова виджетов

Answer (score 1):

отличное начало для CMS. Многое реализовано [link](https://github.com/trntv/yii2-starter-kit)